# What is the purpose of the Storefront Country setting in PS Store configuration?

Tags: psn, region-lock, playstation-store

As anachronistic as it can be, console game stores are still region locked and Sony's PS Store isn't any different in that regard. If your account region is set to US you can't buy games from the JP or EU store. For that reason many user have resorted into creating multiple different separate account, with all the annoyances this brings (more attack surface, needing to switch accounts etc).

The Store settings offer a weird option that allows you to choose a different "store region".

[image]

but as you can see this does NOT allow for purchase of content from a different region.

> You can only make purchases from your home country storefront.

For some time I therefore wondered: WHY would someone want to use such an utterly useless travesty of a setting? Am I missing something obvious? What can I gain by looking at another region store if I can't actually buy anything?

The question is very simple: **Is there any advantage in changing your storefront setting? Can you at least use it to redeem codes from -physical- imported games or anything similar?**  Or is the sole purpose of this getting users angry at Sony by making them see all the games that are not available in their region with no way to buy them?